# WPF Ribbon control with custom RibbonMenuItem

Tags: wpf, user-controls, wpf-controls, ribbon

I'm new to WPF and I'm migrating an application built using Windows Forms to WPF.

My WPF application contains a Ribbon toolbar (from Microsoft office). I have some `RibbonMenuButton` and `RibbonSplitButton` controls on that toolbar.

My main problem is that when I click on the `RibbonMenuButton` I want a user control to appear. For example: consider a phone application that contains a Dial button; When the user clicks that button a Popup should appear for the user to select the phone number and if it's an audio or video call.

[image: what I would like]

What I'm doing so far was creating a Custom Control that extends RibbonMenuItem but then I have problems with the focus of that popup control: I'm unable to press the Enter to click on the default button.

Any suggestions?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

You can use `RibbonGallery` instead of `RibbonMenuItem` and set content for it. 
For example :
`<RibbonGallery>
    <Grid>
        ... 
    </Grid>
</RibbonGallery>`